# Thinking in React: how to have a notification pane that the parent can open/close

Tags: reactjs

I'm still having trouble thinking in terms of message flow in React. What I'd like to achieve is to have a parent component (`Layout`) that has a background activity pane in the bottom right (`BackgroundActivity`), which can be opened by `Layout`, but also has its own control for toggling open/closed. Here's what I've got so far, though it's not working:

```
Layout = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {showBackgroundActivity: false}
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="layout">
        <Toolbar />

        <div className="content">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.content, this.data)}
          </div>
        </div>

        <BackgroundActivity visible={this.state.showBackgroundActivity} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

BackgroundActivity = React.createClass({
  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({expanded: this.props.visible});
  },

  render() {
    let classesPane = classNames({
        'background-activity': true,
        'expanded': this.state.expanded
      }),
      classesExpandBtn = classNames({
        'fa': true,
        'fa-chevron-down': this.state.expanded,
        'fa-chevron-up': !this.state.expanded
      });

    return (
      <div className={classesPane}>
        <i onClick={this.handleToggle} className={classesExpandBtn}></i>

        <div className="processes">
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

So the problem is, initially it will listen to whatever `visible` prop is passed in, but after that, if `Layout`'s `showBackgroundActivity` state changes, nothing happens since `BackgroundLayout`'s render method is not paying attention to the `visible` prop, just the `expanded` state. I could use the prop only, but if I click the expander, I have no way of changing the prop (I could use `setProps` but that's being deprecated since changing props programmatically is not good form).

I know this is probably simple, but I'm not getting it. There has to be some way for a user to expand/collapse `BackgroundActivity` by clicking on it, but also provide `Layout` the ability to expand it upon some event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move Expanded to the parent and pass it as a Prop to the child control. Then add an event call to BackgroundActivity when expanded changes.

```
Layout = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {expanded: false}
  },
  onExpandedChange(expanded) {
     this.setState({expanded: expanded});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="layout">
        <Toolbar />

        <div className="content">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            {React.cloneElement(this.props.content, this.data)}
          </div>
        </div>

        <BackgroundActivity expanded={this.state.expanded} onExpandedChange={this.onExpandedChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

BackgroundActivity = React.createClass({
  handleToggle() {
    this.props.onExpandedChange(!this.props.expanded);
  },

  render() {
    let classesPane = classNames({
        'background-activity': true,
        'expanded': this.props.expanded
      }),
      classesExpandBtn = classNames({
        'fa': true,
        'fa-chevron-down': this.props.expanded,
        'fa-chevron-up': !this.props.expanded
      });

    return (
      <div className={classesPane}>
        <i onClick={this.handleToggle} className={classesExpandBtn}></i>

        <div className="processes">
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh, of course. I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Always keep in mind that state should only be maintained in one place. If you are maintaining it in two places, that is a smell. Once I started consciously thinking about that as I created components, things started to fall into place.